# How to install a specific version of puppet on CentOS 6.6

Tags: puppet, centos6

How can I install a specific version of puppet say 3.8.6 on CentOS 6? When I do `yum install puppet-3.8.6`, it actually installs puppet-agent.xxx.x86_64 and the puppet version within it is 4.x.

I'm setting this up on my mac os x using vagrant + puppet. I'm using vagrant image puppetlabs/centos-6.6-64-puppet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Puppet 3 and earlier you just need to follow the instructions [here](https://docs.puppet.com/guides/puppetlabs_package_repositories.html#yum-based-systems-repository).

```
rpm -ivh https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
yum install puppet-3.8.6
```

In your specific case, however, you are having issues because you are using the puppetlabs/centos-6.6-64-puppet box, and those boxes have Puppet already installed.

The best thing to do would be to instead use puppetlabs/centos-6.6-64-nocm, or alternatively you could remove the PC1 yum repo as well as the Puppet packages that were pre-installed.  Then it should work fine.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your response. I had followed exactly the same steps even before I got your answer and it installs puppet agent and the underlying version is 4.x. Please see this [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a7pT0Xc). What could I be missing?

Comment: Yeah that's interesting, I'll try to reproduce that.

Comment: Ok, I can't explain that.  I just tried it using the Puppet Labs CentOS 6.6 vagrant box, ran those commands and I have me a Puppet 3.8.6.

Comment: Oh hangon, I can explain it.  I can see in your repo list that you have previously also configured Puppet Collections.  Evidently that's taking priority.  Delete those repos, and it'll probably work.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Alex! I disabled the repo /etc/yum.repos.d/puppetlabs-pc1.repo and it installed puppet 3.8.6. Phew!! After a lot of struggle. Can you shed some light on how that repo came in first place since this is a vagrant box? Before installing puppet, I had just installed "rpm -ivh https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm".

Comment: My guess is that you downloaded a Vagrant box image that had Puppet pre-installed.  I use puppetlabs/centos-6.6-64-nocm.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That makes sense. I used puppetlabs/centos-6.6-64-puppet

Comment: can you edit your answer and add the comment about disabling the repo in it so that I can accept the answer.

Comment: I think my answer, as it stands, is the correct answer to the question you asked; you haven't mentioned in your question that you began with the puppetlabs/centos-6.6-64-puppet Vagrant box. Perhaps if you edit the question, I could edit the answer, or we could just mark it resolved as is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108787/discussion-between-sandeep-kanabar-and-alex-harvey).